# shortcut in jquery to $(selector.context).add(context)

Tags: jquery

I am searching for shortcut to add all childerns and the selector itself to jQuery object.

Short way to do something like that:

```
$(selector,context).add(context)
```

I thought maybe .andSelf() can help.. but no.

Comment: Isnt that short enough? :)

Comment: It's short, but in jQuery you never need to type something twice (here I am typing the context twice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#element').children().andSelf()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you want.

To add the context to its children filtered by a selector, use

```
$(context).find(selector).addBack()
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oquzuc/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
$('#parent').find('.child').andSelf()
```